# When change field in array, rest fields disappear, how to render it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have `FieldArray` and each item generate :

```
export const Options = (props) => {   return <div>{
    props.fields.map((op, index) =>
        <Fields
          key={index}
          names={[
            `${props.fields.name}[${index}].${op.fieldName}`,
            `${props.fields.name}[${index}].optionSubList`,
            `${props.fields.name}[${index}].otherValue`
          ]}
          component={SelectList}
          otherValue={op.otherValue}
          fieldName={op.fieldName}
          important={op.required}
          className={op.classNames}
          label={op.label}
          list={op.options}
        />
    )   }</div>; };
```

After I change one of the fields, others disappear.

I tried to add **initialValue**: this does not work, all the same if I have one remaining field missing

I also put a flag **enableReinitialize** same

Comment: Where does the `Fields` component come from?

Comment: FieldArray => Fields => Field x3
It is needed for that would manage Field status (whether or not depending on the value)
You can use FieldGroup but in this case I will not have access to the values of other fields

Comment: If you could post the Field component please. It is essential for finding the full issue. You must post all related code with a question. I am thinking that the issue is that all your fields have the same name, however without seeing how the prop `names` is used inside the `Fields` component it's impossible to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little worried by your `[${index}]` inclusion, since the `props.fields.name` should already have a `[42]` type index on the end of it. I don't know all the details of the adjacent components, but I'd recommend removing the indexes.

```
<Fields
  key={index}
  names={[
    `${props.fields.name}.${op.fieldName}`,
    `${props.fields.name}.optionSubList`,
    `${props.fields.name}.otherValue`
  ]}
  .../>
```